# How to plot percentage above ggplot2 bars when displaying multiple variables in the same plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a few survey questions that allow for multiple selection, leading to each option being recorded as a separate column in the dataset. I managed to create a barplot displaying all options for each question as below:

```
gg_gem <- ggplot(data = df) + 
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = gem_1, fill = gem_1),
           position = "dodge", na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = gem_2, fill = gem_2),
           position = "dodge", na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = gem_3, fill = gem_3),
           position = "dodge", na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = gem_4, fill = gem_4),
           position = "dodge", na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = gem_5, fill = gem_5),
           position = "dodge", na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = gem_6, fill = gem_6),
           position = "dodge", na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = gem_7, fill = gem_7),
           position = "dodge", na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = gem_8, fill = gem_8),
           position = "dodge", na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = gem_9, fill = gem_9),
           position = "dodge", na.rm = TRUE) +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Spectral", na.value="grey") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1)) +
  ggtitle("placeholder")
```

Now I want to display the percentage of n=121 for each of those bars, which I managed to do for single response questions but can't get to work here:

```
gg_ansatz <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = factor(ansatz), 
                                   y = prop.table(stat(count)), 
                                   fill = factor(ansatz), 
                                   label = scales::percent(prop.table(stat(count))))) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge") + 
  geom_text(stat = 'count',
            position = position_dodge(2), 
            vjust = -0.5, 
            size = 3) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Spectral", na.value="grey") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) + 
  labs(x = '', y = '', fill = '') +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1)) +
  ggtitle("placeholder")
```

I think I understand why it doesn't work this way since the second code example uses one variable as the object being referred to in regards to aes and the count obviously not being as simple of a matter but can't seem to find an alternate solution.
I would ideally try to calculate the percentages within the ggplot function instead of pulling from a separate object that stores previously calculated percentages.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data best shared via `dput()`.